# Webpack - CSS not applied

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2

I have decided to give it a try to Webpack 2. I'm trying to bundle js and css.

The problem is that CSS in not being applied the elements on the page (it is present in the built file).

This is the app structure:

```
app
  |-styles.css
  |-app.js
build
  |-bundle.js
index.html
```

webpack config file:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './app/app.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build')
    },
    module: {
       rules: [
          {
            test: /\.css$/, 
            use: 'css-loader'
          }
      ]
   }
}
```

index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
   <script src="./build/bundle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="abc"> hello </div>
</body>
```

app.js:

```
require('./styles.css');
console.log('js loaded!');
```

When I run build command getting this output:

`[0] ./app/styles.css 240 bytes {0} [built] [1] ./~/css-loader/lib/css-base.js 1.51 kB {0} [built] [2] ./app/app.js 148 bytes {0} [built]`

Also I can see the css is included in the bundle.js file

```
exports.push([module.i, ".abc {\r\n    width: 300px;\r\n    height: 100px;\r\n    background-color: red;\r\n}", ""]);
```

If I include css file in html it works fine so I guess there is no spelling mistake in CSS itself. I spent quite a lot of time trying to figure it out. Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You're loading the CSS as a string with just `css-loader`. You'll need [`style-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader) as well in order to have the CSS load into the DOM when you import it.

```
use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
```

Comment: And note that the order is important. Putting 'css-loader' first and then 'style-loader' isn't working for me :)